# C++11 class similar to .Net's ManualResetEvent, but without the ability to "reset"

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, multithreading, thread-safety

The goal is to block all threads that call `WaitOne()`. When `Set()` is called, those threads continue. Any calls to `WaitOne()`, after `Set()`, return immediately. The challenge is to make sure that all calls to `WaitOne()` are either "before" or "after" the call to `Set()`, so that no threads see `_state` false, but miss the `notify_all`. I'm looking for feedback on performance and correctness.

```
#ifndef NO_RESET_EVENT_H
#define NO_RESET_EVENT_H

#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>

class NoResetEvent
{
public:
    NoResetEvent() : state(false) {}
    NoResetEvent(const NoResetEvent& other) = delete;

    void WaitOne() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(sync);
        while (!state) {
            underlying.wait(lock);
        }
    }

    void Set() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(sync);
        state = true;
        underlying.notify_all();
    }

private:
    std::condition_variable underlying;
    std::mutex sync;
    volatile bool state;
};

#endif
```

Comment: std::future<void>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks good.

The only thing I would change is:

```
volatile bool _state;
```

into

```
 std::atomic<bool>  _state;
```

The issue with `volatile` is that it does not universally provide that guarantee that updates are visible to all threads (which std::atomic does).

Could simplify the `wait()` call.

```
    while (!_state) {
        _underlying.wait(lock);
    }

    // could be:
    _underlying.wait(lock,[&state](){return state;});
```

Personally I don't like prefix '_' on identifiers. The rules for using '_' as a prefix are complicated. Even if you know the rules not everybody that reads your code will.

Comment: I sometimes forget to switch naming conventions when switching languages.

Comment: Also, regarding the lambda. I'm thinking that the object construction that goes on in the background might be a slight performance hit. Any insights on this?

Comment: You are going into a `wait()` so who cares about performance you are about to stall the processor anyway 99% of the time. But in reality I doubt there is any object created here (but compile with -O3 and check the assembly if you are worried).

Comment: Regarding synchronization around mutexes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11173020/395029